# landscape... iPhone... accelerometer issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

there is all this....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && interfaceOrientation       != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && interfaceOrientation !=      UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
  } else {
    return YES;
}
}
```

and i want the accelerometer to work in landscape as if it was in portrait... I have all the accelerometer stuff such as:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration {
   accx = acceleration.x;
```

}

also i have tried looking at other questions but i can't find the solution...?

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate more in your question as currently it is not entirely clear what is your problem, at least not for me.

Comment: My iPod app is in landscape... but the accelerometer keeps functioning as if it was in portrait... can i somehow flip the accelerometer or what?

Comment: Ok, when you say it keeps working in landscape, you mean that a view controller doesn't flips to it's landscape position? Or you mean that when reading the accelerometer, you don't get any changes in the reads.

Comment: Ok look. My app works in landscape, its starts out like that and you play in landscape. But, the image on the screen moves in the direction of the tilt. If i was in portrait, i would tilt left to go left and right to go right. In landscape however, the accelerometer, when the device is held flat, is at -1, not at 0. so if i tilt any way it goes left (-1y). Can i Kind of re set the accelerometer so that in Landscape, the number given by the accelerometer i at 0 to begin with (when flat)?

Comment: Say, if i tilt the device (currently) to the right the accelerometer's reading is - 0.5 or something.

Comment: Ive been stuck no this for ages can someone please help...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if understood correctly, you are in portrait (in the X axis direction see the image), tilt right and tilt left then the image in your app should move right and left. Then you switch to landscape and your image should now move right and left but it doesn't, the axis you should pay attention now is the Y axis.

There is no reason why you should not be seeing any change in the Y axis when you rotate to landscape, unless there is hardware damage and that the accelerometer had stopped working.

[image: iPhone Accelerometer]

Now, what you ask for is a way to reset the accelerometer so that you can keep reading from the X even though the changes are happening in the Y axis? No, there is no way to do this, unless you write an extra method ... something along the lines of:

```
+(UIAccelerationValue)fixedAccelerationValue{
    //Check which axis you should look for
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationUpsideDown ){
        //read from the x axis
    }
    else{
        //read from the y axis
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the `BOOL` statement prior to the `UIACCELEROMETER` in the implementation file.

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Hope this helps.